# Am I allowed to tweets for another organisation?

Tags: dataset, twitter, tweets

I've been approached to use my code to collect a dataset of tweets for another organisation - am I allowed to do this?

They would be paying my time to setup a listener and I would give them a set of tweets.

-- edit --

Twitter API terms say I can't redistribute content and lots of freely available twitter datasets have been taken off the web this year.

But I am allowed to to do the above - provide tweets to one organisation?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a Twitter support/policy issue, not programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use the [Twitter Streaming API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-api) to accomplish this. You would setup a listener for your keywords and whenever there is an update, new tweets will be pushed to you.

You may have seen the following clause:

> You may not use Twitter Content or other data collected from end users
>   of your Client to create or maintain a separate status update or
>   social network database or service.

What this basically means is that you cannot **re-create** Twitter. But it is acceptable to collect these tweets for analysis and for usage of the dataset as service augmentation. There are many companies doing this today.

---

https://dev.twitter.com/terms/api-terms

Answer (score 0):

If the organisation gives you permission to tweet on their behalf. Then you should be allowed to do this, as there's loads of apps that send tweets on your behalf - if you agree to letting them.

Comment: Just to clarify - I'm not sending tweets, I'm collecting other peoples tweets. e.g. they want all the tweets that mention #GCSEresults for the next 24 hours and pay me £x to write code and use my server to provide them as a database dump.